# Hide column from Edit form in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, edit-form

I would like to hide a site column from appearing in the EditForm on SharePoint online.

I have been able to achieve this on SharePoint server 2010 by running the following PowerShell.

This will not work in SharePoint Online. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#Get the web and site column objects
$web = Get-SPWeb http://<URL>
$column = $web.Fields["ColumnName"]

#Set the PushChangesToLists property for the changes to be applied to lists where the column has already been added
$column.PushChangesToLists = $true

#Change the ShowInEditForm and other properties and update objects
$column.ShowInEditForm = $false

$column.Update()
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SharePoint online PowerShell.

In that powershell, try below code:

```
$User = "admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$SiteURL = https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site #enter site collection url


#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)

#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

$fieldTitle = "ColumnName"
$customfield = $Context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle) 
$customfield.ShowInEditForm($false)
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Download & install the SharePoint client component SDK  which will give you the CSOM dlls.

Also download the SP online management shell to run the above code.

[SharePoint 2013 Client component SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

[SharePoint online management shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

Comment: This won't work but only a minor change is required: $customfield.SetShowInEditForm($false) 
For some weird reason it is method in SPO and not a property.

Comment: Absolutely dynamite. That worked a treat. Cheers both.

Comment: Why the script initializes  $Creds two times?

Comment: What if there are multiple fields with the same name in different lists? How to specify the list name?

Comment: @spoonboy - can you ask this in a separate question ? Would gladly answer it there. Its out of scope for this question and my answer would be too long for the comment section :)

Comment: Figure out it by myself. I think you can just add one line to your code in order to make it more generic.

Answer (score 5):

With PnP PowerShell Cmdlets

```
Connect-PnPOnline <tenant-site-url>

$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$field = Get-PnPField -Identity <field-name> -List <list-name>

$field.SetShowInNewForm($false)
$field.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

To check if the update took, look for ShowInNewForm="FALSE" in schema xml

```
$field.SchemaXml
```

To install PnP Powershell Cmdlets

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

Please note that this doesn't seem to work if either the column is set to mandatory or content types are used within that list.