# Hide field from New Form in SharePoint Online using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

There is already an answer for doing this with a field name that is unique among lists in a site but I have a field name that is not unique ("Comments") and am trying to figure out how to make the solution linked below specific for a certain SharePoint list.

[Hide column from Edit form in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201232/hide-column-from-edit-form-in-sharepoint-online)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample script for your reference.

```
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll")
Add-Type -Path (Resolve-Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll")

Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,$Password)
{
    write-host Get-SPOContext   
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Password) #SecurePassword
    return $Context
}

$UserName = "lee@xxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString    
$Url = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer"
$listTitle="MyList"
$FieldName="Comment"

$Context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListTitle)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Retrieve field
$field = $List.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($FieldName)
$Context.Load($field)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$field.SetShowInEditForm($false)
$field.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()

write-host Done
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! That worked great! I'm still really new to PowerShell and the SharePoint Object Model. I need to do some studying up on it when I get a chance.