# Error when trying to show a site column in edit and display forms "Method invocation failed because doesn't contain a method named 'ShowInEditForm'."

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, pnp-powershell

i am working on an online classic team site, and i have a site column named "AutomaticallyCreated" which is set to hidden inside create,edit and display form. now i want to show it inside the Edit and display forms, so i run the following powershell script :-

```
$User = "admin@****.onmicrosoft.com"
$SiteURL = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/**** #enter site collection url"


#Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "enterpassword" -AsSecureString
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)

#Bind to site collection
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

$fieldTitle = "AutomaticallyCreated"
$customfield = $Context.Site.RootWeb.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($fieldTitle) 
$customfield.ShowInEditForm($true)
$customfield.ShowInDisplayForm($true)
$customfield.UpdateAndPushChanges($true)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

but i got these exceptions:-

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field] doesn't
contain a method named 'ShowInEditForm'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $customfield.ShowInEditForm($true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field] doesn't
contain a method named 'ShowInDisplayForm'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $customfield.ShowInDisplayForm($true)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

so can anyone advice on this please? the fields should have methods named `ShowInEditForm` & `ShowInDisplayForm`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SetShowInEditForm` and `SetShowInDisplayForm` when using CSOM.

Modify it as below:

```
$customfield.SetShowInEditForm($true)
$customfield.SetShowInDisplayForm($true)
```

Reference - [Field.SetShowInEditForm method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj862472(v%3Doffice.15))

[Field.SetShowInDisplayForm method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj862540(v%3Doffice.15))

Comment: thanks for the reply.. now i am getting this error `Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server
returned an error: (404) Not Found."`

Comment: are you using pnp powershell ? I see that you have tagged the question using that ? Also, please check if you have connected to the correct site collection having the field that you require.

Comment: yes i am running this code using sharepoint online managment shell and i am connected to the site

Comment: also originally i were trying to do something similar to what you have provided in this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201232/hide-column-from-edit-form-in-sharepoint-online  of course in my case i want to show the field instead of hiding it.. and you were using `ShowInEditForm`.. is this correct?

Comment: yes, i guess that is outdated now. The correct method is indeed `SetShowInEditForm`. Not sure why you are getting 404 error. What type of field are you trying to change ?

Comment: single line of text.. i think i have an un-closed `"` .. now the scritp worked well..

Comment: cool, cheers :) happy weekend !